# Trusted Platform Module (TPM) secure password

Tags: passwords, password-policy, trusted-computing, tpm

I'm trying to set secure [Trusted Platform Module (TPM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) passwords on a network and would like to set it to the maximum length possible.

How long can the TPM's password be? Is it limited by bits or by characters? Does anyone has information about this?

**EDIT:** Yes, it's TPM 2.0 modules, embedded on Dell laptops and desktops mostly.It seems that it can be longer than 32 characters but I'm unsure about the (desired) max length. I'm thinking about using a random generator to set up the passwords. Right now I used the Windows' standard password generator for Bitlock.

I do not know much about this, my idea was to set a very secure TPM (and seldom change it) and change the PIN of bitlock protection more frequently.

Comment: Since TPMs are hardware cryptoprocessors, I _suspect_ it depends on the type of TPM you're using. Do you know what types of TPM modules are installed in the computers?

Comment: Not really, from a TPM point of view (not the application using it) it's not manufacturer dependent as it's defined by TCG specs - as describe in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The TCG spec doesn't impose any characters limit for the SRK and owner passwords as they are processed as [hash values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). Briefly, this means that for whatever password length, e.g. with TPM 1.2 it will [always end up](https://github.com/Distrotech/trousers/blob/distrotech-trousers/src/tspi/obj_policy.c#L335-L336) as 20Bytes/160bits (i.e. SHA1 hash).

In reality, the command line tool or the GUI you're using might add some limitations, e.g. the GTK GUI impose a [255 characters limitation](https://github.com/srajiv/trousers/blob/1722374cb9dbab6053a71d9422efc3c50e912197/src/tspi/gtk/interface.c#L233) on the password field.

Comment: As he is using TPM 2.0, the hash functions may be another function than SHA-1 (and should!), TPM 2.0 specs allow other functions such as SHA-2 (224bits/28 bytes, 256bits/32bytes, 384bits/48bytes, 512bits/64bytes) or SM3_256.

Comment: It doesn't change the answer. A hash function doesn't impose a limit on what's to be hashed. Using a better hashing function simply provide better quality (e.g. less collision).